# Only one element is being printed in a tuple

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

In 'stock_list' tuple there are multiple items(printing some of them for reference) but while running the for loop only first item is being printed.

**Here is the output:**

**stock_list :**  ['G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\a', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\aa', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\aapl', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\abbv', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\abc', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\abt', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\ace', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\aci', 'G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\acn']

**each_dir:** G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter/_KeyStats\a

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import datetime as datetime

path = "G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    print(stock_list[1:10])

    for each_dir in stock_list[1:]:
        print(each_dir)
        each_file = os.listdir(each_dir)
        ticker = each_dir.split("_KeyStats\\")[1]

        if len(each_file) > 0:
            #parsing time from the html file
            for file in each_file:    
                date_stamp = time.strptime(file, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.html')
                unix_time = time.mktime(date_stamp)
                #print(date_stamp, unix_time)
                full_file_path = each_dir+'/'+file
                source = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()
                value = source.split(gather+':</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
                #print(ticker+":", value)
                #time.sleep(15)
                return



Key_Stats()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` on the last line of function definition is within the for loop, because of this the function will return on the first iteration, and further iterations will never happen. Actually in python you do not need to write return at the end of the function, it will default to returning `None`.

or change the identation:

```
def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    print(stock_list[1:10])

    for each_dir in stock_list[1:]:
        print(each_dir)
        each_file = os.listdir(each_dir)
        ticker = each_dir.split("_KeyStats\\")[1]

        if len(each_file) > 0:
            #parsing time from the html file
            for file in each_file:    
                date_stamp = time.strptime(file, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.html')
                unix_time = time.mktime(date_stamp)
                #print(date_stamp, unix_time)
                full_file_path = each_dir+'/'+file
                source = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()
                value = source.split(gather+':</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
                #print(ticker+":", value)
                #time.sleep(15)
    return
```